# One of the labels in FrameLabel to be in the top left rather than top middle

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following code:

```
data1 = {{2., 2.97729}, {3., 5.05797}, {4., 9.12475}, {4.9542, 18.}, {5.97728, 31.}, {6.96578, 51.4949}, {7.96578, 76.4315}, {8.96578, 95.}}

data2 = {{2., 2.}, {3., 3.}, {4., 8.}, {4.9542, Around[18., 4.]}, {5.97728, Around[31., 8.]}, {6.96578, Around[53., 3.]}, {7.96578, Around[75., 4.]}, {8.96578, Around[88., 2.]}}


ListLinePlot[{logdata1, logdata02}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, 
LabelStyle -> {24, GrayLevel[0]}, 
PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, 
ImageSize -> Large, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"},
PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{Style["Theory1"], Style["Theory2"]}, 
LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.22, 0.8}]], FrameLabel -> {{Style["% Cities with less crimes"], 
None}, {Style["Ethnity"], A}}, 
FrameTicks -> {{{{20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, "60%"}, {80, 
  "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}, 
None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 
  250}, {9, 500}}, None}}]
```

[image]

How can I change the position of the label in the above "A" to be on the left of the frame instead of the middle?

Comment: Is Ethnity supposed to be Ethnicity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will provide an answer in a general context with a MWE. You need to look up [**`Legended`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)

```
Legended[
 ListLinePlot[Partition[RandomSample[Range[100], 100], 2], 
  Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Directive[18]], {Placed["a", Bottom], 
  Placed["b", {{.91, 1.1}}]}]
```

> [image: plot]

Play with the numbers to adjust the location.

**Edit:** just to make my point clear, the MWE can be applied directly to the specific example in the OP. There's also a mistake in the O.P, the following is the right command

```
Legended[
 ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
     Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[PointLegend[{Style["Theory1"], Style["Theory2"]}, 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.22, 0.8}]], 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["% Cities with less crimes"], 
     None}, {Style["Ethnity"], None}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, "60%"}, {80, 
       "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}, 
     None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8,
        250}, {9, 500}}, None}}], {Placed["A", {{.91, 1}}]}]
```

> [image: legended]

**Edit:** I am getting older. I forgot to mention that we can, of course, customize the text as we want

```
Legended[
 ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
     Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[PointLegend[{Style["Theory1"], Style["Theory2"]}, 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.22, 0.8}]], 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["% Cities with less crimes"], 
     None}, {Style["Ethnity"], None}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, "60%"}, {80, 
       "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}, 
     None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8,
        250}, {9, 500}}, None}}], {Placed[
   Text[Style["A", 25, FontFamily -> "Herculanum"]], {{.91, 1}}]}]
```

> [image: f]

Comment: @Marteen I just prefer this way for customized locations. With the `FrameLabel` you have the `Top`, `Bottom` etc as I showed you in the other post. I never figured out how to customize position in that context.

Comment: @Marteen yes, you are right. I am, also, doing some calculations and providing the answer in a hurry :-)